# How to get instance of entity in limit_choices_to (Django)?

Tags: python, django

For instance:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.OneToOneField(
        'app.Bar',
        limit_choices_to=Q(type=1) & Q(foo=None) | Q(foo=instance)
    )


class Bar(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICE = (
        (0, 'hello'),
        (1, 'world')
    )
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=TYPE_CHOICE,
        default=0
    )
```

I wanna show in Django admin only these Bars that have `type = 1`, that haven't relations with Foo's, and show linked Bar of edited entity (if it is).

Of course, we can do it via overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey` method of `admin.ModelAdmin`, but we want do this via `limit_choices_to`.

How to get instance of edited entity?

Comment: i am not sure if you can do "Q(foo=None) | Q(foo=instance)"  , i'm assuming you want reference to an instance of Foo here

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a callable to `limit_choices_to`, that callable has no reference to the current instance. As such, you can't filter based on the current instance either.

There are several other ways to achieve what you want, such as overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey()` as you mentioned, or overriding the formfield's queryset in the form's `__init__()` method. `limit_choices_to` just isn't one of them.

Comment: also if you pass a dictionary: the filter logic is something like Bar.objects.filter(....) where there is no instance of Foo available.