# Defining a limit_choices_to for a OneToOneField which references the current model

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `Company` and `Package`, with a many-to-one relationship between them: each `Company` can have several `Package`s, but each `Package` has only one `Company`.

In addition, however, I'd like to define a `default_package` field for the `Company` model, which is a `Package`, and I'd like to limit the choices to the packages whose `Company` is the company under consideration.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    default_package = models.OneToOneField(
        'dashboard.Package',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='default_for_%(class)s')


class Package(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, I'd like to add a [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument to the `default_package` field which would be something like

`default_package = models.OneToOneField(..., limit_choices_to={'company': <this_company>})`

where `<this_company>` is a reference to the current company. I'm not what the syntax for this would be, though; can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this question was answered in [How to get instance of entity in limit_choices_to (Django)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593577/how-to-get-instance-of-entity-in-limit-choices-to-django). In short, this is not possible.